# How could i code hard attention in keras?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

How could i code hard attention in keras?
what should i do to make it in my projects?
i tried the soft attention and i can do it but i don't know how can i make the hard one.
i know some reinforcement learning but i didn't implement any algorithm yet. 
i want to make one like the one implemented in "ask attend and tell" http://kelvinxu.github.io/projects/capgen.html

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03044.pdf

Comment: Hi, could you explain me how you did the soft attention in keras?